# Accessing form fields before a custom storage engine with Multer

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, multipartform-data, multer

I'm currently using Multer with a  custom storage engine that uploads a file to a location specified in the request. I'm currently getting the destination and a couple other parameters from the query, but I'd prefer to consolidate all input data into the form data. This destination input requires some extra validation that needs access to `res` and `next`. The current implementation is as follows:

```
upload(req, res, next) {
    // Ideally this would be `req.body.destination`;
    const destination = req.query.destination;
    
    /* Validation ... */

    return multer({
        storage: new CustomStorage(destination),
    }).single('file')(req, res, next);
}
```

However, Multer needs to run before this validation in order to parse the form data into `req.body` in the first place. I attempted to solve this by running a second Multer instance before the storage engine -- this instance would ignore the files and parse any text fields into `req.body`. The implementation was as follows:

```
multer({
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => { return cb(null, false); },
}).any();
```

Running this did allow me to access the form data in `req.body` in the upload middleware, but then I received the following error:

```
Error: Unexpected end of form
    at Multipart._final (/Users/robert/bucket/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:588:17)
    at callFinal (node:internal/streams/writable:694:27)
    at prefinish (node:internal/streams/writable:723:7)
    at finishMaybe (node:internal/streams/writable:733:5)
    at Multipart.Writable.end (node:internal/streams/writable:631:5)
    at onend (node:internal/streams/readable:693:10)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11) {
  storageErrors: []
}
```

I attempted to downgrade to Multer 1.4.3 after reading [issue 1144](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/1144), and doing so did stop the error, but resulted in the API route erroring out with a `400` status and no error message instead.

How can I access the form data fields here?

Answer (score 0):

As you've correctly pointed out, for `req.body` to be populated with anything, Multer needs to run first. Only once you call the Multer middleware, the `req` stream is piped through Busboy (the multipart/form-data request parser used by Multer), and the fields & files get parsed and populated, **in order of their appearance**, to `req.body`.

This means that, **if you send all necessary fields before any of your files**, your `CustomStorage._handleFile()` implementation will have access to `req.body`, populated with fields.

So, to answer your question directly, you can implement field validation inside `CustomStorage._handleFile()` – `req.body` will be populated with fields, **but only those that have been received before any files!** Order of fields/files is important here.

This has several downsides:

1. That strongly ties your validation implementation with Multer's API;
2. There can be cases where you send/received no files, but still want to validate fields.
3. Validation will reduntantly run each time a file is encountered – if you have 3 files, validation on req.body will run three times. This shouldn't have a huge effect on performance, but still, it's not very elegant.

Multer simply isn't designed "flexibly enough" to allow such custom logic, and it doesn't provide functionality to handle field events separately, only files events.

I've written [`pechkin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pechkin) to solve this exact problem.

- `pechkin.parseFormData()` returns a `Promise` that resolves when all fields are parsed, **and** if the first file is encountered (or the request ended).
- The promise contains a populated `fields` object, and a `files` `AsyncIterator/AsyncIterable`.
- No need to provide storage engines, file handlers, event listeners, etc.

This means you can perform validation on the `fields` object, and only then have to mess with files – the files won't be parsed, processed, written to memory, saved anywhere, etc., until you decide to do so. No need to wrap your functionality into a custom storage engine class – files are available as `Promise`s of `stream.Readable` instances.

```js
// ESM
import { parseFormData } from 'pechkin';

// CommonJS
const { parseFormData } = require('pechkin');

// ...

app.post(
  '/upload',
  fileUploadWithFieldValidation(/* ...optional configs */),
  (req, res, next) => {
    // `req.body` will now contain validated fields
    // and `req.files` will be an AsyncIterator that you can iterate over
    // to process files, save them, upload to S3, etc.
    // I.e. do whatever your `CustomEngine` implementation did.
  }
);

// Express middleware
function fileUploadWithFieldValidation (/* ...optional configs */) {
  return async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const { fields, files } = await parseFormData(req, /* ...optional configs */);

      // You can VALIDATE fields here, without having to do anything
      // related to file handling / processing.

      req.body = fields;
      req.files = files;

      return next();
    } catch (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
  }
}
```